# how to update multiple rows in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Base Table1

[image]

Transaction Table

[image]

I want to update my transaction table Brcode based on my base table1.
Can you please help me on this.

```
update trans tl
set brcode = (
  select brcode
  from basetbl tlb
  where tl.accountno=tlb.accountno
);
```

This query taking long run.

Final output
[image]

Comment: Please, [do not use images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551#285557)

Comment: Create an index on `basetbl(accountno, brcode)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query essentially executes subselect as much times as there are rows in your `trans` table. The better approach is to use [`MEGRE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement.

Compare the plans, column `starts` contains the number of executions.
Index on `basetbl.accountno` will improve the performance, but hash join looks better for this task since the large number of rows in `trans` table.

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                        |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:                                                                 |
> | ------------------------                                                                 |
> | update /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/ trans tl set brcode = (   select                     |
> | brcode   from basetbl tlb   where tl.accountno=tlb.accountno )                           |
> |                                                                                          |
> | Plan hash value: 2300756728                                                              |
> |                                                                                          |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name    | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |         |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |     403 | |
> | |   1 |  UPDATE            | TRANS   |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |     403 | |
> | |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TRANS   |      1 |     99 |     99 |00:00:00.01 |       3 | |
> | |*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BASETBL |     99 |      1 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |     297 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                          |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                      |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                      |
> |                                                                                          |
> |    3 - filter("TLB"."ACCOUNTNO"=:B1)                                                     |
> |                                                                                          |
> | Note                                                                                     |
> | -----                                                                                    |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                                  |
> |                                                                                          |
> ```

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                          |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:                                                                   |
> | ------------------------                                                                   |
> | merge /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/ into trans t using basetbl s on (                       |
> | t.accountno = s.accountno ) when matched then update   set brcode =                        |
> | s.brcode                                                                                   |
> |                                                                                            |
> | Plan hash value: 4181434565                                                                |
> |                                                                                            |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | | Id  | Operation            | Name    | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | |   0 | MERGE STATEMENT      |         |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |      15 | |
> | |   1 |  MERGE               | TRANS   |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |      15 | |
> | |   2 |   VIEW               |         |      1 |        |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       6 | |
> | |*  3 |    HASH JOIN         |         |      1 |      9 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       6 | |
> | |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| BASETBL |      1 |      9 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       3 | |
> | |   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TRANS   |      1 |     99 |     99 |00:00:00.01 |       3 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> |                                                                                            |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                        |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                        |
> |                                                                                            |
> |    3 - access("T"."ACCOUNTNO"="S"."ACCOUNTNO")                                             |
> |                                                                                            |
> | Note                                                                                       |
> | -----                                                                                      |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                                    |
> |                                                                                            |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c4c90b0e14fa44c8c9e5889de0713c8e)*